# Markdown and Syntax Highlighting in Django with mixed code

Tags: python, django, syntax-highlighting, markdown

I have some problems with following string while 
trying to syntax highlight them:

Example

```
<code class="php"><? echo "<input type=\"text\">"; ?></code>
```

The php part is rendered correctly, but the html part breaks.

I use the Markdown and Syntax Highlighting snippet from

http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/119/

Any idea how to escape the html part inside the php code correctly ?

Comment: If you tell me in what way my solution doesn't work (what output do you get? What output are you expecting? What errors do you get?) I might be able to help you more. Sorry my answer didn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to pass your PHP/HTML hybrid code through the [`escape`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#escape) filter, to convert instances of `<` to `&lt;` etc.

Use it like this in a template, assuming you've got your code in a template context variable called `mycode`:

```
{{ mycode|escape }}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but it does not work...
i will ask our local python user group this evening 
thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1):

**Python markdown integrates with Pygments that do the syntax highlighting.**

You can go from markdown to html formatted text with source code with highlighted syntax.

The short version is:

```
import markdown
html = markdown.markdown(text,['codehilite'])
```

`html` contains the html formatted text with the source code highlighted. You just need to point to css style, that's it.

Have a look at [how to setup markdow and pygments to do syntax highlight for blogger.](http://mybyteofcode.blogspot.com/2010/01/use-markdown-and-pygments-with-blogger.html)

In your solution you can just include a reference to css which makes it even easier.